# como hago una consulta que contenga varios items

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en donde tengo un rango de año
un grupo de parametros que quiero buscar

mi idea es poder buscar los proyectos que tengan uno o varios de los codigos seleccionados en el ejemplo 4 codigos, y si encuentra q me muestre el resultado. tiendo en cuenta no duplicar el mismo proyecto
por ahora tengo esta SQL

```
select * from proyecto WHERE proyecto.ano BETWEEN '2019' and '2020'
```

en donde tengo la tabla proyecto y otra tabla proyecto_codigos donde estan relacionads por el proyecto_id

```
tabla proyecto
id | nombre |
4    proyecto 1
6.   proyecto 2

tabla proyecto_codigos
id | proyecto_id | codigo_id|
1.     4.           1
2.     4.           2
3.     4.           3
4.     4.           4
5.     2.           5



tabla codigos
id  | nombre_codigo|
1.     10100000
2.     10101500
3.     10101501
4.     10101502
5.     12121221
```

mi resultado seria

4 proyecto1.

Solución final

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.ano, p.n_convenio FROM proyecto p
INNER JOIN proyecto_codigo pr ON pr.proyecto_id = p.id
INNER JOIN codigo c ON c.id = pr.rup_id

WHERE p.ano BETWEEN '2019' and '2020'
AND c.codigo_nombre IN (10100000,10101500)
```

gracias por la ayuda fue muy util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITO
Entendí mejor lo que necesitás. Leí mal.
Es así: tenés que joinear las dos tablas, y poner las condiciones sobre ese join. Por último, para no duplicar el proyecto, deberías agrupar los resultados con un GROUP BY. Para buscar los nombre_codigo, podés usar un IN.

```
SELECT * FROM proyecto p
INNER JOIN proyecto_codigos pc ON pc.proyecto_id = p.id
WHERE p.ano BETWEEN '2019' and '2020'
AND nombre_codigo IN (10100000,10101500)
GROUP BY p.id
```

---

EDITO
Basado en los comentarios, hace falta hacer un join más:

```
SELECT * FROM proyecto p
INNER JOIN proyecto_codigos pc ON pc.proyecto_id = p.id
INNER JOIN codigo c ON c.id = pc.codigo_id
WHERE p.ano BETWEEN '2019' and '2020'
AND c.nombre_codigo IN (10100000,10101500)
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: amigo gracias por responder creo q el IN  pero creo q antes debo hacer un joint cierto? y luego hacer in  pues el nombre_condigo esta en la tabla de proyecto_codigos

Comment: excelente amigo, practicamente lo q necesito. lo unico que veo es que no me fije bien y en la tabla_codigos. solo tengo los campos id, proyecto_id, y codigo_id. en donde el codigo_id es el identicador de otra tabla llamada codigo en donde esta tiene id y nombre. como puedo hacer para que busque sobre esa tabla

Comment: Ahí está editado, fijate si te sirve.

Comment: amigo va bien pero al hacer el group by me dar un error "1055 - Expression #36 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mibd.pr.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"  sera q uso el DISTINCT. gracias por la ayuda esta de un pelo para quedar OK

Comment: Dale, usá el DISTINCT, quizás sea la mejor opción. Saludos! me alegra haber ayudado. Con el DISTINCT y sin el group by no vas a tener problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso debes hacer un `DISTINCT` en la tabla `proyectos` y usar un `JOIN` para validar sobre la tabla `proyectos_codigos`.

Dado la siguiente estructura.

```
Proyectos
id | nombre      | date
1  | Proyecto A  | 2020
1  | Proyecto C  | 2019
1  | Proyecto B  | 2020
```

```
Codigos
id | proyecto_id | Codigo |
1  | Proyecto A  | 01     | 
1  | Proyecto A  | 02     |
1  | Proyecto A  | 03     |
2  | Proyecto C  | 04     |
2  | Proyecto C  | 05     |
7  | Proyecto B  | 03     |
```

```
Tipo Codigo
id | Nombre
01  | Código Uno 
02  | Código Dos
03  | Código Tres
04  | Código Cuatro
05  | Código Cinco
```

Entonces la consulta seria la siguiente, para los proyectos con códigos `01 y 03` de los años `2019 y 2020`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tabla_proyecto.id, tabla_proyecto.nombre FROM tabla_proyecto
JOIN tabla_codigos ON tabla_codigos.proyecto_id = tabla_proyectos.id
WHERE 
 tabla_codigos.codigo IN (01, 03) 
 AND tabla_proyeto.date BETWEEN 2019 AND 2020
```

Esto de devolver algo parecido a lo siguiente.

```
1 Proyecto A  
7 Proyecto B
```

Ahora si requiere el nombre del tipo de codigo, se agrega un `left join` a la consulta anterior.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tabla_proyecto.id, tabla_proyecto.nombre, tabla_tipo_codigos.nombre as 'Código Nombre' FROM tabla_proyecto
JOIN tabla_codigos ON tabla_codigos.proyecto_id = tabla_proyectos.id
LEFT JOIN tabla_tipo_codigos ON tabla_tipo_codigos.id = tabla_codigos.codigo
WHERE 
 tabla_codigos.codigo IN (01, 03) 
 AND tabla_proyeto.date BETWEEN 2019 AND 2020
```

Comment: excelente amigo, practicamente lo q necesito. lo unico que veo es que no me fije bien y en la tabla_codigos. solo tengo los campos id, proyecto_id, y codigo_id.   en donde el codigo_id es el identicador de otra tabla llamada codigo en donde esta tiene id y nombre.  como puedo hacer para que busque sobre esa tabla.

Comment: @avilac3 actualizada la respuesta con tu pregunta, para eso se realiza otro `join` con la table que requieras comparar.